# Problems using a framework that I have created

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks

I'm trying to create a framework to use in some of my projects. Here's what I did so far:

1. Created a framework project;
2. Added a class (myFw) to the framework and set the header to public;
3. Built the framework;
4. Copied the framework from the built folder to a "visible location";
5. Added the framework to one of my projects;
6. Added the path to the framework's Headers to the 'User Header Search Paths'.

When I build my project I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "myFw::myFw()", referenced from:
      Playground::Playground() in Playground.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What am I doing wrong to get this linking error?
Is the problem in the framework or in the project using the framework?

Another thing: Without Step 6, Xcode's autocomplete helps me type the #include for my class and use it in the code, but when I compile it fails to find the header file... I managed to fix this with Step 6 but assume there's a better way for doing this, right?

(I'm using Xcode 4.1 in Lion)

Thanks in advance!